# yajra datatables with vite laravel 10 errors

Tags: laravel, datatables, vite

I'm trying to run a small test regarding Yajra Datatable in Laravel. I'm following the same steps as indicated on the official website, but I keep getting the same errors ,

In the first place, I'm getting the following errors, and I thought that jQuery might be missing.

```
laravel-datatables-vite.js?v=7bd9b31a:28022 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'defaults')
    at laravel-datatables-vite.js?v=7bd9b31a:28022:55
(anonymous) @ laravel-datatables-vite.js?v=7bd9b31a:28022
Show 1 more frame
Show less
users:61 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at users:61:31
```

After importing the jQuery CDN into app.blade.php, I'm getting the following errors.

```
laravel-datatables-vite.js?v=7bd9b31a:28022 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'defaults')
    at laravel-datatables-vite.js?v=7bd9b31a:28022:55
(anonymous) @ laravel-datatables-vite.js?v=7bd9b31a:28022
Show 1 more frame
Show less
jquery-3.7.1.js:3783 jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).DataTable is not a function TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8000/users:66:156)
    at mightThrow (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js:3489:29)
    at process (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js:3557:12) undefined
jQuery.Deferred.exceptionHook @ jquery-3.7.1.js:3783
process @ jquery-3.7.1.js:3561
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ jquery-3.7.1.js:3602
fire @ jquery-3.7.1.js:3223
.........
completed @ jquery-3.7.1.js:3854
jquery-3.7.1.js:3793 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (users:66:156)
    at mightThrow (jquery-3.7.1.js:3489:29)
    at process (jquery-3.7.1.js:3557:12)
```

Please, does anyone have a solution?

............................

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost sure your problem is related to the imports. If you're also importing datatables using CDN you might have to "defer" its load untill the Jquery was loaded.

https://javascript.info/script-async-defer

Your layout should look like this:

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.6.0/dt-1.12.1/af-2.4.0/b-2.2.3/r-2.3.0/sb-1.3.3/datatables.min.js" defer ></script>
```

Another issue could be if you're importing JQuery more than once.

Comment: it's a bug 

https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables-vite/issues/9